# How can I get all post ids for a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/page_id/posts?fields=id to get all post ids from a Facebook page, but I am running into an infinite loop issue with pagination due to paging.next property always returning a url. It looks like the last page points to the first page. How would I know I have reached the end of results.

Here is a code example:

```
public static Dictionary<string,string> GetPagePostIds(string accessToken, string pageId)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> postIds = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(graphAPIURL);
            sb.Append("/").Append(pageId).Append("/posts/?access_token=").Append(accessToken);
            sb.Append("&fields=id");

            string url = sb.ToString();
            int pages = 0;
            int rows = 0;
            while (url != null)
            {
                System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
                System.Net.WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
                string json = null;
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    json = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(json);
                }
                if (json != null)
                {
                    pages++;
                    Dictionary<string, dynamic> data = (Dictionary<string, dynamic>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Dictionary<string, dynamic>));
                    if (data.ContainsKey("data"))
                    {
                        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray a = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)data["data"];
                        foreach (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject o in a)
                        {
                            rows++;
                            postIds.Add(o["id"].ToString(), o["id"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    if (data.ContainsKey("paging"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (data["paging"]["next"] == url)
                            {
                                //otherwise we will be stuck in the infinite loop, as next url of the last page is not null
                                break;
                            }

                            //if next link is present, there are more pages available
                            url = null;
                            url = data["paging"]["next"];
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return postIds;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break the loop, if you reach to the point, where you only receive empty results.

So you just simply extend your while loop with a second condition. Here is some simple pseudocode:

```
while (url != null && resultsOnPage) {
  [...]
  if (data.ContainsKey("data") && data['data'].Count > 0 ) {
    [...]
  } else {
    resultsOnPage = false;
  }
  [...]
}
```

Just leave the rest as it is.

Comment: The problem is that data is not empty and paging.next is always not empty.  After few pages, next points to the first page.

Comment: Okay then add a duplicate check and break the loop if you get a post ID twice.

Comment: I wanted to avoid relying on the duplicate post showing up to indicate I have went through all the pages.  Is this a bug in the API pagination?

Comment: I haven't found a page, where the paging of results loops infinitely. Can you provide me a concrete page id? You could also check https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/trending/ for bugs or otherwise report it. Anyways, if you are looking for a termination condition, you could use the created_time field. The results are in descending order. If you find a created_time stamp, that is greater than the previous one, you could break the loop.

Comment: Here is an example https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/20767777944/posts/?access_token=TOKEN&fields=id